# How to read all string inside parentheses using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I wanted to get all strings inside a parentheses pair. for example, after applying regex on

```
"fun('xyz'); fun('abcd'); fun('abcd.ef') { temp('no'); "
```

output should be

```
['xyz','abcd', 'abcd.ef'].
```

I tried many option but was not able to get desired result.
one option is
`/fun\((.*?)\)/gi.exec("fun('xyz'); fun('abcd'); fun('abcd.ef')")`.

Comment: So, why did you ask here when you already have the answer? http://www.rubular.com/r/rWMUMS8a36

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the regex in a variable, and run it in a loop...

```
var re = /fun\((.*?)\)/gi,
    string = "fun('xyz'); fun('abcd'); fun('abcd.ef')",
    matches = [],
    match;

while(match = re.exec(string))
    matches.push(match[1]);
```

Note that this only works for global regex. If you omit the `g`, you'll have an infinite loop.

Also note that it'll give an undesired result if there a `)` between the quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code will almost do the job:

```
"fun('xyz'); fun('abcd'); fun('abcd.ef')".match(/'.*?'/gi);
```

You'll get `["'xyz'", "'abcd'", "'abcd.ef'"]` which contains extra `'` around the string.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to find what you need is to use this RegExp: `/[\w.]+(?=')/g`

```
var string = "fun('xyz'); fun('abcd'); fun('abcd.ef')";
string.match(/[\w.]+(?=')/g); // ['xyz','abcd', 'abcd.ef']
```

It will work with alphanumeric characters and point, you will need to change `[\w.]+` to add more symbols.